# Filter a txt(GTF) file based on another file

Tags: python, awk

Can someone please help me with an AWK problem? 
I have a big GTF file like below. The 9th field contains gene_id I want to use.

**file1.gtf**

```
chr1  hg38_refGene  exon         67127166   67127257   0.000000  -  .  gene_id  "NR_075077";  transcript_id  "NR_075077";
chr1  hg38_refGene  exon         67131142   67131227   0.000000  -  .  gene_id  "NR_075077";  transcript_id  "NR_075077";
chr1  hg38_refGene  exon         67134930   67134971   0.000000  -  .  gene_id  "NR_075077";  transcript_id  "NR_075077";
chr1  hg38_refGene  start_codon  201283703  201283705  0.000000  +  .  gene_id  "NM_000299";  transcript_id  "NM_000299";
chr1  hg38_refGene  CDS          201283703  201283904  0.000000  +  0  gene_id  "NM_000299";  transcript_id  "NM_000299";
chr1  hg38_refGene  exon         201283452  201283904  0.000000  +  .  gene_id  "NM_000299";  transcript_id  "NM_000299";
```

I then have another file which has all the gene_id I would like to filter out from the rest.

**file2.txt**

```
NM_000017
NM_000019
NM_000024
NM_000033
NM_000034
```

I would like the out put to be a filtered file1 with rows with gene_id I want to keep. Other solutions in python would also be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: post the final result

Comment: and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
awk -F'"' 'NR==FNR { ids[$1]=1;next } ids[$2]' file2.txt file1.gtf
```

First create an array with the ids you want to filter from file2.txt, then for every record on file1.gtf only print the line if the field $2 (split records by ") is one of the ids in the array.

Comment: More commonly written `awk -F'"' 'NR==FNR { ids[$1];next } $2 in ids' file2.txt file1.gtf` so you're not creating entries in `ids[]` for every unwanted $2 in file1.gtf. Right idea though.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for the insightful feedback!

Answer (score 0):

try following awk and let me know if this helps you, it will save the ids which are common in file1.gif and file2.gif and save the output into same file1.gif too.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{array[$2]=$0;next} array[$1]{print array[$1]}' FS='"' file1.gif file2.txt > temp_file  && mv temp_file file1.gif
```